# error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option. Changing properties does not resolve the issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a native VC++ (MFC) project. I want to enable /clr option for my project so I can start using syntax like

```
using namespace System::Data;
```

but even after I change my project properties -> Common Language Run time Support -> /clr. 
I am still getting the C1190 error. Please help :(

Answer (score 2):

1. project properties -> Common Language Run time Support -> /clr
2. project properties -> C/C++ -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Answer (score 0):

From googling C1190:

> You are using Managed Extensions for C++ constructs and the /clr compiler option, but you **did not explicitly include mscorlib.dll** [emphasis mine].
>
> Managed targeted code requires `#using <mscorlib.dll>` and `/clr` option.

Did you add `#using <mscorlib.dll>` to your code?

Comment: Hi rodrigo I made some changes in my project and was getting whole lot of other errors so i decided to start from scratch. there is no new code in my project at the moment. I just go and change the project settings to use /clr but after this change i am not getting the following error: 
error D8016: '/clr' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible'
any help with this?

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx): at the bottom it says how you can disable the `/RTC1` option.